# Meaning of occupation codes in Maine Town Register?

Tags: 20th-century, directories, maine

What is the meaning of 'ph' in records? I found this abbreviation in the 1906 Town Register of Jefferson, Lincoln County, Maine next to my grandfather's name. He was listed as ptr, and ph. His name was Harry Avery.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Can you give us a better citation for the source you looked at?

Answer (score 5):

Harry Avery was a painter and paper hanger.

If you consult the full text of [The town register: Waldoboro, Nobleboro and Jefferson, 1906](https://archive.org/details/townregisterwald00mitc) at archive.org, page 101 explains some of the common occupation abbreviations including ptr (painter).

If you search for the abbreviation ptr in the same document, you'll find quite a few ptrs, and also some ptr & pap hgr, or ptr & paper hgr. I suspect they had to abbreviate it further in Harry's case (to "p h")