# Seeking US death record from about 1912?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, death-records, maine, new-jersey

The family story says that my Grandfather Harry Avery died sometime in 1912.

- In 1906 he was in Jefferson Maine. [PAINTER AND PAPERHANGER].
- In 1908 he was in Attleboro, Massachusetts where he married my Grandmother, Margaret Hanratty [April 29 1908].
- In 1912 he was listed in the Newark, New Jersey, City directory as a painter, living in rooms at 228 Bank Street, Newark.
- He is not listed in the city directory 1912 to 1915.

I have a copy of his marriage certificate but to date I have not found a death record or reference to his whereabouts.  I have tried death records and cemetery records in New Jersey and in Maine.

I never knew him. Can anyone help?

His wife left the USA around September 1912 listed as a housewife. She returned to the UK and remarried in 1915. Her UK marriage cert. states that she was a widow, Margaret Avery. There is no confirmation of Harry's death recorded.

In the US Census 1930 there is a Harry Avery and his wife, Angeline, [no maiden name] in Newark NJ . Harry was listed as a carpenter not a painter - it also states that he was '27 at first marriage.

Comment: Related [question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13506/4485) on the same man.

Comment: From the (likely) [marriage record](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:N4XV-TJP), Harry Elton Avery was born in 1881 in Augusta, Maine.

Comment: You need to show a little more research detail. Have you followed up in the city directories to verify that he is gone after 1912? (Is his wife still in Newark and listed as widow or remarried?) Have you looked for him in the WW1 Draft registration? Have you found the family in the 1920 census; could is he still be in the household or are there any children born after 1912/1913? Have you looked for a newspaper obituary, both in New Jersey and his hometown? If he left his family (other than through death), was there a divorce or other legal action?

Comment: Ihave a copy of the marriage cert.He is not listed in the city directory 1912 to 1915. I have tried death records and cemetery records in New Jersey and in Maine. His wife left the USA around September 1912 listed as a housewife. She returned to the UK and remarried in 1915. Her UK marriage cert. states that she was a widow, Margaret Avery. There is no confirmation of Harry's death recorded. In the US Census 1930 there is a Harry Avery and his wife, Angeline,[no maiden name] in Newark NJ . Harry was listed as a carpenter not a painter - it also states that he was '27 at first marriage..

Answer (score 1):

I have a death record for a Harry Avery from 22 Mar. 1912 who died in Granville, Ohio, which seems to go along with this:

https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/21048286

Comment: Not my grandfather - his parents were  were George E Avery and Oridell Sprague [named on his marriage cert. 1908  in MA].